# requirements for CFB encryption mode

Tags: encryption, cfb

In my course there is a remark saying that in CFB encryption mode, the plaintext must not a multiple of the block length.

Why?

Answer (score 2):

CFB mode has no such length restrictions; it can be used to encrypt an arbitrary length plaintext.

Perhaps you misunderstood what was said.

Comment: That's what I thought. But it is clearly written black on white. Thanks for the confirmation :)

Answer (score 2):

For CFB mode the input *does not have to be* a multiple of the block size; i.e. no padding or ciphertext stealing is required as with the ECB or CBC mode of operation.

Maybe that has been badly translated into "must not" as in "is not required to".